# Task/Job scheduling on PHP

Tags: php, cron, gearman, beanstalkd

Our system based on Zend 1 has a background process running as daemon to check hourly whether user has expired or not, if yes, the system will send verification email to these expired users.

The code is really simple:

```
while(1) {
    $worker = ... //get verification worker
    $worker->run();

    sleep(3600); //run hourly
}
```

We would like to look for better approach with free tool to replace this code to schedule job in the system. Zend Job Queue is really good approach but it is commercial.

My thinking on two below approaches as Zend Job Queue alternative:

1. Instead of running daemon, configure cron jobs on crontab to run PHP script hourly, but I am not sure whether it is better on above code or not.
2. Run [node cron](https://github.com/ncb000gt/node-cron) on nodejs server to call PHP script directly.

I also have looked on Gearman and beanstalked whether they supports on job scheduling but really stumped on this way.

Please suggest if there is any better approach to schedule task on PHP.

Comment: Use native `crontab`; long running PHP scripts tend to fail at a specific point in time. `sleep(3600);` is not accurate either.

Comment: @DanFromGermany: thanks for comment, beside long PHP running tend to fail at specific point in time, are there any other points which crontab is preferable in this case? I'm quite new on this stuff, my case does need accurate point of time.

Comment: `crontab` is easy to maintain (you can group jobs using the `/etc/cron.d` folder), it is accurate in timing (max off I've seen is 1 second). I am running a few hundred cronjobs on a single server using crontab and all work great.

Answer (score 2):

Cron would definately be the preferred way to automate tasks, and not a php script in an infinite loop.

see : http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cron

You many also want to consider using Zend Server which includes a component called Zend Job Queue which provides offline asynchronous processing of tasks and activities.

see : http://files.zend.com/help/Zend-Server-6/content/jobs_component.htm

see : http://www.zend.com/en/products/server

Comment: Thanks for answer since Zend Server is commercial, is there any free tool as Zend Job Queue to schedule jobs?

Comment: The most widely used free tool is crontab on linux machines you can install it via yum or aptitude and the sheduling format is simple to use and well documented. If you are on windows you could use Windows Task Scheduler.

Answer (score 0):

```
0      *      *       *       *       /usr/bin/php -q /yourpath/verification_worker.php
```

you can use crontab to run this task every hour

Hope this helps